# Scroll only in one element on the Stack

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I love css.

This is probably a very simple task, but I have absolutely no idea how to solve it.

**Purpose**: I want to scroll only in `List`, but it scrolls the whole page

Page structure:

```js
<Stack>
    <Box>Header</Box> // static height
    <Box>Content</Box> // dynamic height
    <List sx={{ overflow: 'auto', pb: '50px' }}> // dynamic height, need scroll only here
        <ListItemText>Lorem Ipsum #1</ListItemText>
             // ... more Lorem
        <ListItemText>LAST LAST</ListItemText>
    </List>
</Stack>
```

| before scroll | after scroll |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of your header and content to fixed? I would also advise setting the ``overflow`` property of your ``List`` to be ``scroll`` instead of auto.

Comment: @ItzHex postion fixed pushes elements out of the stream. Accordingly, the List will move to the very top. I can't set it to top because the Content has a dynamic height.
`overflow: scroll` didn't help

Comment: You could maybe use some javascript to give the ``List`` a ``margin-top`` of the same height as both the ``Header`` and ``Content``'s height? Might be a bit of a hacky solution though.

Comment: @ItzHex, yeap, a little bit :) maybe smth cleaner...

Comment: For scrolling to work, you need to give your `List` a fixed height. Then, if you scroll over the `List`, only it will scroll, not the entire page.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen yes! But I don't know height. It should be equal to the rest of the screen

Comment: @Daniel Try giving it a fixed height of something like `400px` and let me know if it works.

Comment: If it works, we can find a way to make it the height of your viewport.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen Yes, of course, if you set the height less than the remaining to the edge of the screen, it works like a charm

Comment: Can you explain exactly what do you mean by *rest of the screen*?

Comment: What is the height you want for this `List`?

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I changed screenshot in question. I hope it's clearer?
`List`  height must be equal `remaining screen height`

Answer (score 0):

Since, the content height is dynamic, there is no way in CSS, to target it. One way would be to make your root container a flex box, and set the container's height to `100vh`, then use `flex: 1` on your content, `height: var(--header-height)` (which is some fixed height for your header) on your header, and similarly, fixed height on your navbar, and finally, `flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: var(--minimum-list-height);` on your list. However, this will result in unwanted behavior when content is too large to contain on a single page, and will force the list out of the page, and set `flex-grow: 0` on it.

The better way would be to make the list expand to fill the screen while the content is too small. And, once the content grows larger, you set fixed height on your list, and make the content grow as much as it wants. To do that, you will again make, your root container, a flex box, set fixed height on your header, `flex: 1 0 var(--minimum-content-height)` on your content, `flex: 1 0 var(--minimum-list-height)` on your list **while content is too small to push the list towards the page end**. Then, once the content grows larger, use script, to set a fixed height on your list, and `flex-grow: 0` on it.

The exact breakpoint where you change the height rules for your list occurs when:

```
content_height + header_height + (others including navbar) > viewport_height - minimum_allowed_list_height
```